# Форматированные таблицы в NetBeans

Tags: forms, java, netbeans

Необходимо создать на форме java applet таблицу 9х9, чтоб она выглядела как поле для судоку, то есть каждый третий разделитель был жирный, не было заголовков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант на Swing: 9 больших JPanel скомпонованных при помощи GridLayout(3,3), то есть у нас есть поле 3 на 3. Внутри каждой из них по 9 JLabel, JButton или что там вам еще взбредет в голову, скомпонованных также (3 на 3).

Если нужно детальнее, напишите, что конкретно прояснить?